# jquery get previous form element

Tags: jquery, forms, dom

This is an example code,

```
<select id="select1">
     <option value="1">Option 1 </option>
     <option value="2">Option 2 </option>
     <option value="3">Option 3 </option>
     <option value="4">Option 4 </option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="input1"/>
<select id="select2">
     <option value="1">Option 1 </option>
     <option value="2">Option 2 </option>
     <option value="3">Option 3 </option>
     <option value="4">Option 4 </option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="input2"/>
```

My question is, let say I use jQuery to grab an input field, i.e. $("#input1"), how can I grab the previous form element without hard coding? In this case it is $("#select1"), I dont want to manually travel through the DOM with prev(),parent(),children(), etc., because my form structure can change in the future (like add fieldset, td, tr, etc.)

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You want to get the previous form element, but you don't want to use prev(), because things can change??? If that is the case, what do you consider "previous form element"?

Comment: @Steve, the form elements might be separated by `fieldset`s or similar.

Answer (score 2):

use the jquery `prev()` method

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

```
$("#input1").prev();
```

will return the select element before the input

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/m8Tst/1/

you can use the length property to check whether the previous element exist before accessing that.

Comment: he didn't want to use prev, though.

Comment: sorry for not getting my question clear, i mean i can use the .prev() but i dont want to manually travel through the DOM since my form structure can change. please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rocker_9x/bCCpb/1/

Comment: @user826224: You want the element in the previous td ? you have to define your requirements more clearly

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem.

```
//pass in the id of the current input
function selectPrev(input) {
    //find parent form, then get all descendant input-type elements
    var inputs = $("#" + input).parents("form").find("input,select,textarea");

    var prev = -1;
    //loop through list of inputs to find current input
    inputs.each(function(i, el) {
        //select previous input once current is found
        if (el.id == input) prev += i;
    })

   return inputs[prev];
}​
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQ63E/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's .prev() method, but specify the elements you want it to look for, in your case other form fields.

```
$("#input1").prev('select,input,textarea');
```

As the documentation for [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) says:

> The method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type
>   that can be passed to the $() function. If the selector is supplied,
>   the preceding element will be filtered by testing whether it match the
>   selector.

Comment: I follow what you said but it only shows 'undefined'
http://jsfiddle.net/rocker_9x/bCCpb/1/

Comment: Ah, well the structure in your recent jsFiddle is different from the original so .prev() won't work since the select isn't a previous element of the input. You would need to go the up and down route of prev, parent, and so on to do what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Not a easy way on this. You could write a small plugin to do the job:

```
$.fn.previousFormElement = function () {

    var element = this[0],
        $formElements = $("input, select, textarea"),
        previousFormElementIndex = $formElements.index(element) - 1;

    return $formElements.eq(previousFormElementIndex);

};
```

See the [Fiddle with a running example](http://jsfiddle.net/alextercete/tgwAw/). I should note that this only works if you call the `previousFormElement` on an element that satisfies the selector `"input, select, textarea"`. An added bonus is that if you run the plugin on the first form element on the page, it gives you the last.